# Free $\Phi$-cocompletion of a category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

let $\Phi$ be a class of small categories (for example, finite categories). A category $D$ is called *$\Phi$-cocomplete* if it admits all *$\Phi$-colimits*, i.e. for diagrams of the form $I \to D$ with $I \in \Phi$. A functor is called *$\Phi$-cocontinuous* if it preserves $\Phi$-colimits. Now it is a well-known result that every category $C$ admits a *$\Phi$-cocompletion* $\Phi(C)$, which is a $\Phi$-cocomplete category equipped with a functor $C \to \Phi(C)$ which induces an equivalence of categories between the category of $\Phi$-cocontinuous functors $\Phi(C) \to D$ and all functors $C \to D$, where $D$ is a $\Phi$-cocomplete category.

I want to understand this construction as detailed as possible. I've seen sketches of it in many papers. For details the authors often refer to Kelly's book *Basic concepts of enriched categories*, in this case section 5.7. But for me this is too complicated and I would prefer a more direct and down-to-earth exposition (hopefully avoiding all the theory of Kan extensions). Besides I'm not interested yet in the specialities of enriched categories. Perhaps someone knows a nice and understandable reference?

Here is what I've already understood: Consider the Yoneda embedding $Y : C \to [C^{op},\mathrm{Set}]$. Close the image under isomorphisms and under $\Phi$-colimits; this is done by a transfinite construction. If $\Phi$ is small, then this construction stops after some ordinal (and otherwise it stops after some ordinal outside of the universe?). So we get a $\Phi$-cocomplete full subcategory $\Phi(C) \subseteq [C^{op},\mathrm{Set}]$. We claim that $Y : C \to \Phi(C)$ is the desired cocompletion. So let $F : C \to D$ be a functor to a $\Phi$-cocomplete category $D$. What is the definition of the induced $\Phi$-cocontinous functor $G : \Phi(C) \to D$? It is clear what to do on $Y(C)$. Probably the rest is transfinite recursion? If $y \in \Phi(C)$, then $y$ is a $\Phi$-colimit of objects $y_i$ for which $G(y_i)$ has already been constructed. Let us also assume that the action on morphisms has been constructed, then we get a diagram and we may take the colimit $G(y) := \mathrm{colim}_i G(y_i)$. This must be the right definition on objects. Now if $y \to y'$ is a morphism, how can we define $G(y) \to G(y')$?

Finally I would like to ask for more specific descriptions of $\Phi(C)$. For example, if $\Phi$ is the class of all finite categories, i.e. we want to adjoin finite colimits, then why is every object of $\Phi(C)$ a coequalizer of two morphisms between finite coproducts of representables? Again this seems to be well-known, but I couldn't find a reference which explains this directly. It seems to be a result concerning distributivity of finite coproducts and coequalizers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think the approach with Kan extensions and weighted colimits is actually quite insightful. Let me try to explain it briefly.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a locally small category. Recall that the colimit of a diagram $X : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{D}$ weighted by a presheaf $W : \mathcal{J}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is an object $W \star_\mathcal{J} X$ equipped with bijections
$$[\mathcal{J}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](W, \mathcal{D}(X, D)) \cong \mathcal{D}(W \star_\mathcal{J} X, D)$$
that are natural in $D$. The diagram $\mathcal{J}$ need not be small for this definition to make sense. This is sometimes also called the functor tensor product. It is clear that ${-} \star_{\mathcal{J}} {-}$ is functorial and preserves colimits in both variables, and the Yoneda lemma implies
$$Y (j) \star_{\mathcal{J}} X \cong X (j)$$ 
for all $j$ in $\mathcal{J}$. Thus, if $W$ can be expressed as an iterated $\Phi$-colimit of representable presheaves and $\mathcal{D}$ has $\Phi$-colimits, then $W \star_{\mathcal{J}} X$ exists in $\mathcal{D}$.

Now take $\mathcal{J} = \mathcal{C}$, $X = F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and assume $\mathcal{D}$ has $\Phi$-colimits. By what we said before, $P \star_{\mathcal{C}} F$ exists in $\mathcal{D}$ as long as $P$ is in $\Phi (\mathcal{C})$, so we obtain a functor ${-} \star_{\mathcal{C}} F : \Phi (\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ which preserves $\Phi$-colimits and which extends $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ along the Yoneda embedding $Y : \mathcal{C} \to \Phi (\mathcal{C})$, as required.

Obtaining an explicit description of $\Phi (\mathcal{C})$ seems to be a difficult problem in general and indeed relies on facts about distributivity of colimits in $\mathbf{Set}$. I thought about the finite limit case a few months ago but I didn't find a reference either.

Comment: I already knew this description using coends in the case that $\Phi$ consists of all small categories and didn't realize that the same works here. Thanks a lot. Somehow I was confused since the formula $\hom(P \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} F,T) \cong \hom(P,\hom(F(-),T))$ suggests that $- \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} F$ is a left adjoint and therefore preserves all colimits. But this seems to be wrong, since $\hom(F(-),T)$ doesn't have to belong to $\Phi(C)$.

Comment: As for the remaining question: I've read this as Lemma 5 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1545v1.pdf. The author refers to a statement in Kelly's *Structures defined by finite limits in the enriched context*. Again I don't get it.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't see the connection either, but I haven't studied the paper carefully. The way I would do it is to show that the class of presheaves obtained as colimits of finite diagrams of representables is already closed under finite colimits: for finite coproducts this is obvious, and for coequalisers one builds a diagram that looks a bit like a bipartite graph.

Comment: Alright. The reason is basically that every representable is projective. Then every map from it into a cokernel already maps into the domain of the cokernel, so we can add this etc.